Уменьшить масштаб сайта на CSS
Есть код на увеличение масштаба сайта в зависимости от разрешения экрана.
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width: 1700px) {
  body {
    zoom: 1.4814 !important; /* Old IE only */
        }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2035px) and (max-width: 3700px) {
  body {
    zoom: 1.067 !important; /* Old IE only */
                    }

Вопрос следующий. Как на CSS уменьшить, а не увеличить масштаб от 100%. То есть сделать скажем 80%. Потому что данный код только увеличивает масштаб от 100%, но не уменьшает. Он рассчитан на увеличение от 100% с 1080P. А что если нужно пропорционально уменьшить на 1360. Что пишется вместо zoom для уменьшения ?

Попробуйте zoom: 0.8 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Пробовали, никакой реакции. Должен же быть на CSS какой то символ для уменьшения.
